# SSRS Calculate between subreports

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I've got an SSRS report, where the data is such that the only way I have been able to figure out how to get the report correctly populated is using subreports. That piece works fine, but what I need to do is have another field where I compute the difference between subreports. So, basically I need an expression that does Subreport1.value - Subreport2.value. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just take the datasets populated from each one and put it in the main report?  I don't think SSRS can see the objects inside of a subreport to my knowledge.  You would need to put one or many values into different tables, matrices, or text boxes for each dataset as you cannot mix datasets in a single object.  Then you could take the column values and do aggregates on those.  EG: ReportItems!(nameoftextbox).value - ReportItems!(nameofothertextbox).value.